# Slide menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, menu, slide

I'm working on a new header for a website, and my header works perfectly on codepen. You can check it out at:

http://codepen.io/germangallo/pen/eNeKWG

As you may see, if you click on the menu button (categories) it slides a menu that I've done following the steps by `callmenick` here:

http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

However, when I've tried to make it work at my site, everything is great, but the slider menu doesn't work. I'm new at JavaScript, so I really don't know if the problem is there, and I can't figure out any way to fix the problem.

My site is: http://www.pensarpoker.com/nuevo

Comment: It looks like it's having a problem with your `querySelector` function on line 215 of your page. `this.closeBtn = this.menu.querySelector('.c-menu__close');`.  It may be halting execution of your script.

Comment: Thank you Victor :) I've reviewed it but I don't know how to make the querySelector works. I've tried it in local and it doesn't work either, so it only works at my CodePen. Do you know any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you script is executing before the dom element is accessible on the page, try adding your slider script to the bottom of the page or wrapping it in a $( document ).ready() if your using jQuery.